# Extension for tracking bandwidth in asterisk

Tags: asterisk, tracking

I have an asterisk PBX system and I would like to track the bandwidth that is consumed in each call.

I have found http://www.asteriskguru.com/tools/bandwidth_calculator.php which gives an indication of the bandwidth that is consumed in each call based on the codec that is used.

I have searched around but I couldn't find an extension in asterik, something like the bandwidth calculator, which would log in the database, the bandwidth for each call.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Asterisk is VOIP PBX.
It can collect info about voice Qos, but not care about bandiwdth.

For manage bandwidth use specialized tools.

Something like libpcap/capture, mrtg etc.